# How to selectively enable class member depending on class constructor's argument in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates

```
class Name
{
    explicit Name(int payloadFormat);
     
    // If payloadFormat = 0 then only enable format0member
    int format0member;

    // If payloadFormat = 1 then only enable format1member       
    int format1member;
};

int main()
{
    payloadFormat = 1;
    obj = Name(payloadFormat);
}
```

I am trying to break down a message payload using a class.
Basically by matching each bit with a named variable.

However, in my case, there are 2 types of format for the message which lead to very different named variables to match.

Therefore, it is really needed to only define or enable member variables that correspond to the correct format.

Is there any possible way to only enable certain member variables inside a class according to the class contructor's parameter such as this code snippet?

Comment: smells like an XY-Problem.  What are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: Can you elaborate about your use-case for such thing please? It's unclear what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I have updated some more info of the actual use case for my question. Thank you so much for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe a better approach is having two different types, possibly polymorphic?

Comment: What do you mean by "enable"?    There is nothing to prevent constructors storing the value of `payloadFormat` and then for all operations (member functions) only doing things with  `format0member` if `payloadFormat` is equal to zero, otherwise only doing things with `format1member`.   But you will need to write the code to do that checking in EVERY member function (and appropriately handle any errors).     There is no way to simply make one member non-existent in some circumstances.

Comment: A class definition can't depend on runtime values. If these are different types, you most likely really want them to be different types.

Comment: Maybe consider having a `map` in `Name`?

Comment: Class is static thing in C++. If you want different data for different cases, there are many techniques, including: `std::any`, `std::variant`, `union` (C style), use of templates (very C++ style, produces different class type for different cases), using OOP polymorphism and factory pattern... What is the right choice depends on many details, and is also a matter of opinion.